# Python How to check range of certain chars in a string, multiple times?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a string

```
s = "nnbbbnbbbnnnnbb"
```

How would I check the range of "b's" while it's seperated by "n's". I want it to look like:

```
arr = [(2,5),(6,9),(13,15)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

result = []
n = 0
for c, g in groupby(s):
    g = list(g)
    if c == 'b':
        result.append((n, n + len(g)))
    n += len(g)
```

Result with `s = "nnbbbnbbbnnnnbb"`:

```
>>> result
[(2, 5), (6, 9), (13, 15)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.finditer` for that

```py
import re
s = "nnbbbnbbbnnnnbb"
arr = [(m.start()+1, m.end()) for m in re.finditer(r"nb+", s)]
# or
# arr = map(lambda f: (f.start()+1, f.end()), re.finditer(r"nb+", s))
print(arr)
```

Comment: A simpler approach would be to use a lookback on the `n`, then you don't have to adjust the start and can use `m.span()` instead.